# Check types in argument of generic function and return object literal type of this argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### My Task

I have two interfaces.

```js
interface ComponentOptions<Props> {
  abstract?: boolean;
  functional: boolean;
  props?: Props;
  name?: string;
  render?(props: Props): boolean;
}

interface ComponentProps {
  title: string;
  dark: boolean;
}
```

I need to realize a function that

- takes an interface to substitute the `Props` generic type
- does any checks connected with the `Props` type in function argument object
- returns an object literal type, based on the passed argument object

  - does not return `ComponentOptions<Props>` interface

`strict: true` compiler option required.

### Actual Solution

I have implemented `createComponent` function that recieves two arguments:

- required `options` object literal
- `props`, treated as imaginary argument for type casting

```js
function createComponent<
  Props,
  Options extends ComponentOptions<Props>
>(options: Options, props: Props): Options {
  props;
  return options;
}
```

I achieved the desired result with such an realization. But I don't really like it.

```js
const component = createComponent({
  abstract: true,
  functional: true
}, {})

const componentWithProps = createComponent({
  functional: false,
  name: 'bar',
  props: {
    title: 'bar',
    dark: true
  },
  render(props) {
    return props.dark
  }
}, {} as ComponentProps)
```

### The Problem

I want to get rid of `props` argument to left only `options`, and to set the type for props using a generic parameter, not casting the `props` argument.

It might look like this:

```js
const component = createComponent<ComponentProps>({
  functional: true,
  props: { // Check 'title' and 'dark' types
    title: 'comp',
    dark: true
  },
  render(props) { // Pass type for the props
    return props.dark;
  }
})

// When we hover on `component` variable,
// display all defined properties in the `options`
{
  functional: true,
  props: ComponentProps,
  render(props: ComponentProps): boolean
}
```

How to achieve this?

### [Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsC2AHdILgDy2YweAzgDwAKU625AfMgN4BQyycARuWFIjAB+AFzJu6dABsIcEAG4OyGAFcQCUnjhSxE6bIVLsdBqOS165RZxBxMEM3yigA5teRQCAE2hCAFMaWYhYMAJS6kjJyigC+bGygkLCIKBg4eARgIeSsSqRgMmJOru5ecFAA1hH60WxxbAD0DcgAYoLozhDk8arqmiDICJ5wkGm4+OCUStkANErE-TkQAB6QIF45YxlEJGQgVNmMbIx+9ItiC3vkM8iBDMEm5OHIlxS5nHdWSp5gKlADZyusXiTSaaCw40yORBzQA6h0Kq54ggKGBBhDtmiALyDYajDETMB+dicHhOQRifgqCBzTi9DR7bSUqDUuo3FgxULI1Ho9KE2HAMAAC2yyBxQ1k+L5mWJSnp-SZym05BpSls9jEAHJuOVNbTbo8xCTOMh8oVkNrdfrOGVKszWZwYvrPOtoAFHqF3iafn8Bp8AHS2ipKOJO1gxLibAmZbJcoA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this solution:

```js
interface FunctionalComponent<Props> {
  <Options extends ComponentOptions<Props>>(opts: Options): Options
}

function createFunctionalComponent<Props = {}>() {
  return (o => o) as FunctionalComponent<Props>;
}

const component3 = createFunctionalComponent<ComponentProps>()({
  functional: false,
  name: 'bar',
  props: {
    title: 'bar',
    dark: true
  },
  render(props) {
    return props.dark
  }
});
```